# React field onChange not firing when value gets inserted programatically (hooks, not classes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing an app (from full stack open) which will search through countries, and display country information if only one country is selected. 
The application works well when a human uses it, however, if more than 1 country is displayed, I want the user to be able to click a 'show' button next to the country name, and display the country information for the given country.
 I figured I could just create a function that changes the search field's value, and set the value to the given country's name. 
My problem is, that the onChange on the input doesn't fire when it gets filled out programmatically.

I've tried create a new hook just for the input field, but I couldn't get that to work either.
How can I go about making my onChange trigger when the field is filled programmatically?

I want to do this in the function `toggleShowCountry`

Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';


function App() {

  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(countries);
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState("");

  const fetchCountries = () => {
    axios 
    .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(response => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  };
  useEffect(fetchCountries, []);

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchField = document.querySelector('#searchCountry').value;

      setSearch(Object.values(countries).filter(country => 
        country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())))

  }

  const toggleShowCountry = (props) => {

    const searchField = document.querySelector('#searchCountry');
    searchField.value = props;

  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Search countries</h2>
      <Search handleSearch={handleSearch} />
      <Display countries={search} toggleShowCountry={toggleShowCountry} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Display = (props) => {

  const countries = props.countries;
  let filteredCountries = countries.map(country => country);

  if (countries.length > 10){
    return(
      <>
        <p>Too many matches, specify another filter.</p>
      </>
    )
  } else if (countries.length === 1){
    return (
      <>
      {filteredCountries.map(country =>
        <div key={country}>
          <ShowCountry country={country} key={country} />

        </div>
      )}

      </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <>

        {filteredCountries.map(country =>
          <ul key={country.name}>
            <FilteredCountries country={country} key={country.name} toggleShowCountry={props.toggleShowCountry}/>
          </ul>
        )}
      </>
    )
  }
}

const FilteredCountries = (props) => {
  const country = props.country;
  return (
    <>
      <li>{country.name} <button onClick={() => props.toggleShowCountry(country.name)}>Show</button></li>
    </>
  )
}

const ShowCountry = ({country}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{country.name}</h2>
      <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
      <p>Population: {country.population}</p>

      <h3><strong>Languages</strong></h3>
      <ul>
        {country.languages.map(language => 
          <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
      <img src={country.flag} alt="flag" width="100px"/>
    </>
  )
}

const Search = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="countries">Enter country </label>
          <input name="countries" id="searchCountry" onChange={props.handleSearch} />
        </div> 
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setSearch also and then it work:

```
const toggleShowCountry = (props) => {
  const searchField = document.querySelector('#searchCountry');
  searchField.value = props;
  setSearch(Object.values(countries).filter(country => 
    country.name.toLowerCase() === props.toLowerCase()))
}
```

See in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s505973

Comment: Oh my! I cant believe I was THAT close to the solution, and didn't see it.  I guess I got too hung up on changing the field value. Great job finding the solution. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The input `onChange` event handler only gets called when the input loses focus which means that it won't get called unless you force the input to lose focus or call the onChange result manually. Like Denis Stukalov showed. :)